# rest api - what is this return data format?

Tags: python, rest

So I'm trying to parse this data into a csv or list (to manipulate with python). This clearly isn't a json format (from what I googled) that is returning.

Question: What is this format?

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d 'plan=11' https:/example.com/rest/api/m_spl/search
```

{"COLUMNS":["Value1","Value2", "Value3", "Value4"],"DATA":[]}

"DATA":[["Data1","Data2\nData2a","","Data3"],…}

Thanks

Comment: Thi is a JSON format. You can check it from any online json formatter.

Comment: It's JSON. What makes you think it's not? How did you try to parse it? Is the COLUMNS and DATA part of the same structure?

Comment: Your curl implementation probably includes some command options that will output the HTTP response headers.  The `Content-Type` header will give you a hint about how the origin server expects you to interpret that representation.

Comment: does anyone know how to parse it into a csv or list? is there a package that does this?